# How do I move master back several commits in git?

Tags: git, git-reset

I have a git repository which holds a Drupal site.  I spent the last day trying to build a feature using several different modules.  I have given up on my current approach and have decided to try a different combination of modules.  However, my repository has several commits on the master branch that contain this feature development process (I understand that I did not branch in an effective manner.)  I want to get rid of the last three or four commits and set master to that point in my history (I don't want to merge my current work with anything, I just want it to go away.)  How do I do this?

Comment: Have you already pushed your changes to the `remote`?

Comment: I am not currently using a remote.  I will probably set that up in a few days

Comment: possible duplicate of [Revert to previous Git commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-previous-git-commit)

Comment: Looks like the same answer.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

In order to do it locally, you can do the following commands to go to master and move it to the old commit.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard <old_commit_id>
```

If you then want to push it to the remote, you need to use the `-f` option.

```
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: Could I ask for a good place to find a list of options that git uses and their meaning?  I don't know what --hard or -f does.

Comment: Actually, I just found this documentation link : https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html

Comment: @Mr JF, That is true.  One must unprotect to rewrite history.  There's no other way.

Comment: lots of merit in the backup strategy suggested by william_grisaitis

Answer (score 20):

Before pointing `main` to a previous commit, I recommend backing up your current `main`:

```
$ git checkout -b main_backup
```

Then you can safely point `main` some number of commits back, e.g. 3:

```
$ git reset --hard main~3
```

After moving `main`, see your tree of commits:

```
$ git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all
```

Now, I would recommend keeping the backup until you're absolutely sure it's unnecessary (for instance, once your new approach is fully implemented), but when you're sure, you can clean up by deleting `main_backup`:

```
$ git branch -D main_backup
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always do a `git reset <commit>`. Perhaps the easiest way to do this is use a graphical frontend, i.e. `gitk`.

You should perhaps first do a `git branch branch-for-failed-experiment` so the work on the experiment isn't lost forever.

Be careful, if you published the branch (i.e., if others could have work based on your to-be-deleted commits), they will be left stranded. Make sure they sync up with you.

Comment: I don't think I want anyone ever to know how bad I messed that one up :P

Comment: It sounds like what I really want to do is make a new commit in which all the mistakes are removes (which would look identical to a commit made 3 or 4 commits ago.)  How would I do that?

Comment: You can revert the commits. Or you could do something like `git diff <old>..<current>`, stash the result away in a file, and then `git apply -R` this to undo all changes, then `git commit -a` the result. But I'd prefer to create a clean history (even if it is completely fake).

Answer (score 1):

Note that at any given time you can change where a branch points to by using `git update-ref refs/heads/branch id` , but before you do this, you must give a name to the tip of the tree, otherwise your work will unaccessible. So these two commands may do the job

```
 git update-ref refs/heads/newfeature HEAD
 git update-ref refs/heads/master XXYYY
```

But make sure that you do not have any uncommited changes otherwise all hell will break loose